# Psn account log in

Tags: psn

In how many PS3 can I log in with my account of psn?

I would stay at my cousin place like for 2 weeks and I want to download some games from my account to play there.

Answer (score 0):

You can log into as many PS3s as you want to, but you can only share games with 2 different PS3s.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Since I alredy bought a PS4 but hasn´t arrived. Does that count as the two? or is just 2 ps3 and tha´ts it?

Comment: @Zarathustrax It counts for PlayStation 3 systems only. PSN has no limit on the number of PS3s or PS4s you can login to as stated in the answer. The trouble comes if you try to download one of your PSN games on that other PS3 console if you've already assigned your account to two PS3s already.